# Generate a random chain with cauchy distribution using C language

Tags: clustering, simulation, cauchy-distribution

Here is my question:

I want to simulate a random variable using cauchy distribution with C language. Scale and position must be setted manually.

I fuond the GSL library wich contain the function: gsl_ran_cauchy (const gsl_rng * r, double a)

the problem that i can't unsterstand how to fix the position and the scale and there is not a lot of documentation about that.

Regards

cauchy-sequence simulation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generating from a Cauchy distribution is easy enough that you don't need a library function to do it.  Generate $U$ uniformly in $[0,1]$ using your favorite generator, then apply the formula:
$$
X = m + s \tan(\pi(U-1/2))
$$
where $m$ is the location and $s$ is the scale parameter.  This is comes from the formulas available on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution).

Answer (score 1):

If you are not strictly bound to C, and C++ is an option for you as well, the Boost-Library might be an interesting and easy to use alternative:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/dist_ref/dists/cauchy_dist.html

Here you can explicitly set the location and the scale parameter.

Comment: thank you for your response, I am not strictly bounded to C but I'am trying to compare between the performance of the two languages for the same algorithm (Metropolis-Hasting)

Comment: I am not sure if you can say that you are actually comparing the performance of C vs. C++. Essentially, you are using libraries. The performance that you measure will depend on the library that you used: e.g., the random number generator, or the transformation to the (e.g.) Cauchy distribution. The actual overhead of Metropolis-Hastings is negligible.

Comment: With any computer you should be able to generate a vast number of samples per second - C or C++ (or the library used) will not change that. The underlying model is usually the one that will slow down your algorithm considerable; i.e., the computation of the target distribution at the proposed sample point.

Comment: Exactly, I am doing a homework to show the difference between to languages (C and C++). Thanks a lot for your help